# Unexpected plots on matplotlib histograms

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, deep-learning, data-science, data-analysis

I am quite a beginner with matplotlib so apologies if this seems like a dumb question.

I have a csv file with weight values for individual neurons in the different layers of my deep learning model. As I have four layers in my model, the file structure looks like this:

> weight_1,weight_2......weight_n
>
> weight_1,weight_2......weight_n
>
> weight_1,weight_2......weight_n
>
> weight_1,weight_2......weight_n

I want to extract the weights from each layer and generate the distributions out of it. I already have a code for it and it's working but for some epochs, the histograms have some weird colors which look like more histograms. I am attaching a sample image with the question. [image: sample histogram]

As you can see, there is some pinkish part which is masked by the blue bulk of the histogram. Can someone please help me to understand what is that?

My code currently looks like this (assume that my file is loaded in the reader):

```
        for row in csv_reader:
            a = np.array(row)
            a_float = a.astype(np.float)
            plt.hist(a_float,bins=20)
            plt.xlabel("weight_range")
            plt.ylabel("frequency")
```

Please note that FOUR different plots (images) are generated after finishing the loop as the csv file has four rows. I have only posted the sample image for one of them. I didn't try to plot all the rows in one graph.

**EDIT**

I reduced the number of bins and now it's more prominent. I am attaching another sample image.[image: another_sample]

**SOLVED**

Adding plt.figure() inside the loop solved it. Please check the comments and answer below for the details. The updated loop should be as follows:

```
        for row in csv_reader:
            a = np.array(row)
            a_float = a.astype(np.float)
            plt.figure()
            plt.hist(a_float,bins=20)
            plt.xlabel("weight_range")
            plt.ylabel("frequency")
            plt.close()
```

Comment: This is multiple histogram. You are plotting several distribution one by row of your CSV.

Comment: Presumably each plot belongs to one `row` from `for row in csv_reader:`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's correct. As I have four rows in my CSV file, I will have four such plots. I have only attached one for the sake of an example.

Comment: @jlandercy , as I said, I have one plot for each row. The attached image is just one sample. I also tried some traditional debugging by printing out the shape of the rows received from the reader and it's one dimensional. So I am quite sure that I am only feeding one-dimensional input to plt.hist(). I am not sure how I might be plotting multiple histograms. If I am by any chance, can you recommend how to correct that?

Comment: I figured it out! I thought that plt.hist() creates a new histogram by default. I didn't know it used the previous one. So I just added plt.figure() in the loop and it helped. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce your error, and most likely you are plotting several histograms in one plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arrays = np.array([np.random.random() for i in range(200)]).reshape(2, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for array in arrays:
    ax.hist(array, bins = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Nico P. Do you recommend reinitializing the "figure" inside the loop? Let me try it out and I'll let you know if it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. I added plt.figure() inside the loop so it treated it as a new plot every time instead of overwriting on the previous one. As I said, being new to matplotlib, I didn't really know that is how it worked. I just assumed, plt.hist() creates a new histogram.

Comment: Matplotlib always plots on the last axes. This means, that if you don't create a new axes (like you do inside a loop with plt.figure()) then all the data will be plotted on the same axes. That's why you have overlapping histograms. If you need more help, you might find useful this tutorial: https://www.kaggle.com/python10pm/plotting-with-python-learn-80-plots-step-by-step